# Are there any sources of historical land use/land cover data for the United Kingdom and Ireland?

Tags: united-kingdom, geography, reference

Are there any sources of historical land use/land cover data for the United Kingdom and Ireland? (Not just Northern Ireland) I'm specifically interested in datasets that, for each point/area in the UK/Ireland (ideally, at the resolution of a parish, since I'm studying historical deforestation at the parish level), list whether the land was forest, urban, agricultural/cultivated, etc. for the time period 1800-1900.

There are modern versions of these data, e.g. the [Corine land cover data](https://catalogue.ceh.ac.uk/documents/32533dd6-7c1b-43e1-b892-e80d61a5ea1d), which have been addressed in [other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193344/126188) [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/181659/126188), but nothing historical.

The [Ordnance Surveys](https://maps.nls.uk/os/6inch-england-and-wales/) supposedly include some data like this for the years 1842 onward, but actually looking at the [list of years in which each county was mapped](https://maps.nls.uk/os/county-series/dates-england-and-wales.html) shows that the actual data is mostly much later.
https://maps.nls.uk/os/6inch-england-and-wales/

---

<sub>See [this meta question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3864/14615) for a brief discussion about the suitability of this question for history.SE.</sub>

Comment: This is an X-Y problem: a question on a complex proposed solution to an unknown problem. I.e. the phrase"*as a high a resolution as possible*" is impossible to meet without knowing the actual resolution your actual problem requires. Are you actually interested on lot-by-lot resolution possible available from tax records? Please explain the actual problem behind this request, and more detail on why you see this solution as ideal.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My problem is studying historical deforestation at the parish level. I added that detail and specified that the resolution I need is that of the parish level.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Do you know if any data or maps like these exist?